# Change $(this) css property 'of focus alone' on click of selectected textarea

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following HTML:

```
    <textarea class="new" id="1"></textarea>
    <textarea class="new" id="2"></textarea>
```

As well as this CSS:

```
.new {
    height:60px;     
}

.new:focus {
    height:80px;
}
```

When the textarea gains focus (the user clicks on or tabs to it) I want its height to be changed to 100px, but only if its value is a non-empty string. How can I achieve this?

**Update::I want textarea to function like twitter**

Thanks for reading

Comment: @captain how, can u give an example

Comment: You want to use pseudo CSS class :focus or js/jquery focus handler? As when you click on element this bring it focus, why not only use CSS here?

Comment: @captain
my code of jquery looks like this
$('.new').live('keyup',function(){
   if($(this).val().length>0){

Comment: @rickj You are confusing me, you talk about click event but seems to use keyup event. So what are you using and what are you expecting?

Comment: @ A. Wolff 
I have used that and its included in my code but the problem is , I want its height to be increased through out the page , when its length is > 0

Comment: I hope you have used twitter , in that when u click on tweet its textarea increases , I want to make it similar to that

Comment: `live` is deprecated .Use Use `.on()` to attach event handlers

Comment: @captain dude I need to detect even length, so if length > 0 then height would be 100px else 60 px

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer what is being asked. If I've misunderstood feel free to rollback to the previous edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will increase the height of a textarea if it is focused, and keep the increased height when loosing focus if its content is not empty.

```
//html
<div class="container">
    <textarea class="new" id="1"></textarea>
    <textarea class="new" id="2"></textarea>
</div>

//css
.new {
    height:20px;     
}
.new:focus, .new.notEmpty {
    height:80px;
}


//javascript
$('.container').on('change', 'textarea.new', function(){
    var notEmpty = $(this).val().length > 0;
    $(this).toggleClass('notEmpty', notEmpty);
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rFAe/3/)

It is not recommended to use `.live()`, use [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8110934/direct-vs-delegated-jquery-on) instead.

`$('.container').on('change', 'textarea.new', ... )` is an example of delegation. If you don't have any natural container to target, use `$(document).on( ... )`.

Comment: +1 Works for me, I don't understand the point of increasing it to 100px however, I would just have one style for both rules: `.new:focus, .new.notEmpty { height:80px; }`, but my guess is this is because of OP requirements.

Comment: @Curt: true, it's better to have one single rule to set the size. Updated the answer

Comment: @LeGEC thnks a lot , would u mind explaing the jquery part alone

Comment: var notEmpty = $(this).val().length > 0;
    $(this).toggleClass('notEmpty', notEmpty); what does this do